# display column in select query not added in group by clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

i am stuck in creating a sql query.

Table:

```
XX_AR_RECEIPT_CREATE
```

Columns:

```
RECEIPT_ID                 
ENTITY                    
LOG_ID                    
ACTIVITY_ID               
FIN_CLASS                 
RECEIPT_METHOD            
RECEIPT_AMOUNT            
RECEIPT_TYPE              
RECEIPT_NUMBER     
RECEIPT_DATE              
POSTED_DATE               
ACTIVITY_DATE             
SERVICE_DATE              
CASHIER_NAME              
CASHIER_USERNAME          
PAYMENT_REFERENCE_NUMBER  
DEPARTMENT                
SPECIALITY                
ACCOUNT                   
STATUS
```

This is my query

```
select to_char(sum(to_number(receipt_amount))) amount,entity, cashier_name, 
       receipt_method, fin_class,to_char(to_date(posted_date, 'dd/mm/yy HH24:MI:SS'), 'dd/mm/yy') as receipt_date
from XX_AR_RECIPT_CREATE
where to_number(receipt_amount)>0 and status='0'
group by entity, cashier_name, receipt_method,
         fin_class, to_char(to_date(posted_date,'dd/mm/yy HH24:MI:SS'), 'dd/mm/yy');
```

it's working fine, the problem is that i wanted to add some extra columns example LOG_ID. But i can't add it in Group By clause.
EG:

```
select to_char(sum(to_number(receipt_amount))) amount, entity, cashier_name, 
       receipt_method, fin_class,to_char(to_date(posted_date, 'dd/mm/yy HH24:MI:SS'), 'dd/mm/yy') as receipt_date,
       LOG_ID
from XX_AR_RECIPT_CREATE
where to_number(receipt_amount) > 0 and status = '0'
group by entity, cashier_name, 
         receipt_method, fin_class, to_char(to_date(posted_date, 'dd/mm/yy HH24:MI:SS'), 'dd/mm/yy');
```

I have searched in the internet too for the solution. inner join was a good solution. But the problem is i am using to_char() so I can't add alias with that. I am using Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide which `LOG_ID` you want.  For instance, to get the minimum:

```
select to_char(sum(to_number(receipt_amount))) as amount, entity, cashier_name, 
       receipt_method, fin_class,
       to_char(to_date(posted_date, 'dd/mm/yy HH24:MI:SS'), 'dd/mm/yy') as receipt_date,
       min(LOG_ID) as LOG_ID
```

Or to get a list of them (that is not too long):

```
select to_char(sum(to_number(receipt_amount))) as amount, entity, cashier_name, 
       receipt_method, fin_class,
       to_char(to_date(posted_date, 'dd/mm/yy HH24:MI:SS'), 'dd/mm/yy') as receipt_date,
       listagg(LOG_ID, ',') within group (order by LOG_ID) as LOG_IDs
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon I just forgot the listagg(). this will help me.